# Lock screen shows user name instead of disclosing and just showing empty textboxes

Tags: lockscreen, sonoma

I use macOS Sonoma and did the following settings for the lock screen:

- disable showing username and foto (German "Benutzername und -foto anzeigen")
- only show name and password (German "Name und Passwort")
  [image: settings]

But instead of just showing empty text fields and disclosing the user accounts, I still see names and logos for users, as in the following image.
[image: lock screen]

Does anybody know what's wrong here? Could this be a bug in Sonoma?